# Index for large bit strings

Tags: postgresql, index, index-tuning, performance, postgresql-performance

I'm trying to extend PostgreSQL to index bit strings up to 1000 bits. (These bit strings are created by quantization of high-dimensional vectors, so for each dimension up to 4 bits are assigned). Insertions are rather infrequent, whereas searches are the mostly used operation. In a search, I would like to get all the rows that exactly match the bit string.

It looks like a perfect job for GIN (in combination with my own data type), or what do you think?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> In a search, I would like to get all the rows that exactly match the
> bit string.

Use a B-Tree index, the default type. I don't see a case for a GIN index here.

Up to 1000 bits result in up to 133 bytes (or slightly more) storage size on disk for a [`bit varying` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-bit.html).

```
SELECT pg_column_size(repeat('1', 1000)::varbit)  -- 133
```

Not *that* much. A plain B-Tree index should do. But maybe the column is big enough that the following tricks improve performance.

If a small part of the bitstring column is distinctive enough to narrow your search down to few hits, an [index on an expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) *might* give you better performance, because the smaller index can fit into RAM and is faster to process all around. Don't bother for small tables, the overhead would eat the benefit. But could make a big difference for *big tables*.

#### Example

Given table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(id serial PRIMARY KEY, b_col varbit);
```

If the first 10 bit are enough to narrow down a search to a few hits, you could create an [index on the expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) `b_col::bit(10)`. [Casting to `bit(n)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-bit.html) truncates the `bitstring` to n bit.

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_b_col10_idx ON tbl ((b_col::bit(10)))
```

Extra parentheses are required for the cast operator in an index definition. See:

- [How to create an index on an integer json property in postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54539/how-to-create-an-index-on-an-integer-json-property-in-postgres/54549#54549)

Then, instead of the query

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE b_col = '1111011110111101'::varbit; -- 16 bit
```

You would use:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  b_col::bit(10) = '1111011110111101'::bit(10) -- utilize index
AND    b_col = '1111011110111101'::varbit;  -- filter to exact match
```

Be aware that shorter values are padded with `0`'s to the *right* (least significant bits) when cast to `bit(n)`.

In a real world application this starts to make sense with several 100s of bits. Test for the turning point.

#### Optimize further

Since most installations operate with a `MAXALIGN` of 8 bytes (64 bit OS) ([more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/939860)), your index size is the same for any data not exceeding 8 bytes. Effectively, per row:

```
4 bytes item identifier
8 bytes for the index tuple header (or 23 + 1 byte for heap tuples)
? actual space for data
? padding to the nearest multiple of 8 bytes
```

Plus some minor overhead per page and index / table. Details [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html) or in this [related answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/939860).

Therefore, you should be able to further optimize the above approach. Take the first **64 bit** (or last or whatever is most distinctive and works for you), cast it to `bigint` and build an index on this expression.

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_b_col64_idx ON tbl ((b_col::bit(64)::bigint))
```

I cast twice (`b_col::bit(64)::bigint`) for there is no cast defined between `varbit` and `bigint`. Details in this related answer on SO:

- [Convert hex in text representation to decimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8335376/939860)

Effectively, this is just a very fast and simple hash function, where the hash value also allows to look up *ranges* of values. Depending on exact requirements you could go one step further and use *any* `IMMUTABLE` hash function - like `md5()`. [See link above.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8335376/939860) Or

The query to go along with that:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  b_col::bit(64)::bigint = '1111011110111101'::bit(64)::bigint  -- utilize index
AND    b_col = '1111011110111101'::varbit;  -- narrow down to exact match
```

The resulting index should be just as big as the one in the first example, but queries should be considerably faster for three reasons:

- The index typically returns *much* fewer hits (64 bit of information vs. 10 bit)
- Postgres can work with integer arithmetic, which should be faster, even for a plain `=` operation. (Didn't test to verify that.)
- The type `integer` has no overhead like `varbit` - [5 or 8 bytes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-bit.html). (In my installation 5 bytes for up to *960 bit*, 8 bytes for more).
  Effectively, to keep the index at its minimum size, you can only pack *24 bit* into a `varbit` index - compared to *64 bit* of information for a `bigint` index.

#### `CLUSTER`

In such a case `CLUSTER` should improve performance:

```
CLUSTER TABLE tbl USING tbl_b_col10_idx;
```

The command rewrites tables and indexes and holds an exclusive lock until finished, which can take a while for big tables. The effect deteriorates over time with write operations to the table. Repeat at intervals of your design. Be sure to read [the manual on `CLUSTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html). Or consider the community tools like [pg_repack](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack) or [pg_suqeeze](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_squeeze). See:

- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

If the first 64 bit of your values are unique most of the time, `CLUSTER` will barely help, since the index scan will return a single row in most cases. If not, `CLUSTER` will help *a lot*. Consequently, the effect will be far greater for the first example with the less optimized index.

Comment: For whatever reason the dual casting with :: inside of `CREATE INDEX` did NOT work. 
 However:  `CREATE INDEX on table  ( CAST(CAST(somebitstring as bit(64))as bigint));` worked beautifully.  Thank you, fantastic post!  (i'm on Postgres 12.2 BTW)

Comment: @Marcin: Sorry, an extra set of parentheses is required. Fixed and added a link to explain.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter amazing answer, I just improved a query that was taking 15 sec to 100 ms with your `::BIT(64)::BIGINT` trick! On a table with millions of rows and a column `BIT(256)`. Just wanted to let you know that there is a typo in your post and I can't edit it myself because edits must be at least 6 characters: I suppose "Casting to bin(n) truncates the bitstring to n bit." was meant to be "Casting to bit(n) truncates the bitstring to n bit.".