# How to create an index on an integer json property in postgres

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-9.3, cast, json

I can't figure out for the life of me how to create an index on a property of my json column which is an integer.

I tried it this way (and also dozens of others)

```
CREATE INDEX user_reputation_idx ON users(("user"->>'reputation')::int)
```

It works just fine in a query (e.g. `ORDER BY ("user"->>'reputation')::int`)

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I'm getting a simple syntax error, however, I really have no clue why.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "::"
LINE 1: ... user_reputation_idx ON users (("user"->>'reputation')::int)
```

The table definition is quite simple. It's just one column `user` of type`json`.

So, looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  "user" json
)
```

Comment: You need to provide the verbatim error message and the (relevant part of) your table definition (`\d tbl` in psql), as well as the query you are trying to run. [For starters, this related answer on SO may be of help.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706) That one is for indexing a json *array*, though. Your case seems simpler ...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm aware of that other answer and I'm already using this index for arrays as described there successfully. I also use another index on a `json` property which holds simple `text`. Just for this `int` column it doesn't work. However, using it in a query to sort as `int` works great. And btw, thanks for your great support here!

Answer (score 16):

Try this instead:

```
CREATE INDEX user_reputation_idx ON users(cast("user"->>'reputation' AS int));
```

The [Postgres syntax shortcut `::` for casts](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) is not allowed without additional parentheses in an index definition ([see @bma's comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54539/how-to-create-an-index-on-an-integer-json-property-in-postgres/54549#comment98059_54549)). It works with the standard SQL function, though: **`cast(expression AS type)`** This is not related to the `json` type per se.

Either way, you can still use the syntax shortcut `expression::type` in expressions that utilize the index.

Comment: Great! That worked. There is just a closing parenthesis missing in your query. Thanks for saving my day again!

Comment: With enough brackets it should work. Eg `CREATE INDEX user_reputation_idx2 ON users ( (("user"->>'reputation')::INT) )`. I recall reading an answer in the pg lists where Tom Lane explained why the expression needed the extra brackets, but a quick search didn't turn it up.

Answer (score 0):

As @bma explained in a comment, your index will work as-is, if you add double parentheses around the entire JSON definition:

```
CREATE INDEX user_reputation_idx ON users((("user"->>'reputation')::int));
```

Make sure you consistently use the JSON text notation [->>], not the JSON object notation [->], in the index and when referencing the field in a query, or the index won't be used.

Alternatively, you can consistently use the object notation [->].  You just have to stick to one or the other, don't mix them.