# Creating a unique constraint on a PostGIS 'raster' type column

Tags: postgresql, constraint, postgis, raster

I am using the following command to add constraints to one of the raster image in PostGIS-2.1.3 (PostgreSQL-9.1.14).

```
ALTER TABLE schema1.table1 ADD CONSTRAINT enforce_scalex_rast unique (rast);
```

But getting the following errors:

```
ERROR:  data type raster has no default operator class for access method "btree"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
```

Kindly someone help me to fix this error up. I have no basic idea about the operator classes. Thx.

Zia.

Comment: What datatype is `rast`?

Comment: @Colin'tHart `raster`; per the error message.

Comment: @Colin'tHart: It is raster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A unique constraint creates a unique index to implement the constraint. The only index type in PostgreSQL that supports unique indexes is the default b-tree index type; you can't make a unique GIN or GiST index, e.g.:

```
regress=> create unique index indexname on test USING GiST(id) ;
ERROR:  access method "gist" does not support unique indexes
```

Data types must specifically support different kinds of indexing, and this data type doesn't seem to support b-tree indexes. So you can't make a unique constraint on this type.

---

Details:

There are a few index types used by PostgreSQL. Types must provide an operator class for each index type they support. For your purposes there are really two groups of interest:

- b-tree - the default, what you get when you don't say the index type. Supports equality, less-than, and greater-than operations. Supports creation of unique indexes.
- GiST and GIN - popular flexible index types, used heavily by PostGIS, fulltext search, etc. Does *not* support creation of unique indexes. Supports more kinds of comparisons than b-tree.

Most data types support b-tree indexing, which is the default, by providing a b-tree operator class.

Some data types, especially those used in GIS, don't provide a b-tree opclass, either because nobody wanted one, or because it doesn't make much sense.

This type seems to be one of them. Nobody's added b-tree support for the `raster` type, so you can't create a b-tree index on it. As only b-trees are supported for unique indexes, and a unique constraint creates a unique index to implement the constraint, that means you can't make a unique constraint on a `raster` type.

You might find that a newer PostgreSQL/PostGIS version has the desired opclass. Or might not. I haven't checked. Either way, you're out of luck in 9.1.

---

Lets try [creating an operator class](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createopclass.html) for b-tree support of the `raster` type. The [docs on operator classes and families](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-opclass.html) shows the [strategy numbers for the b-tree index strategy](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xindex.html#XINDEX-BTREE-STRAT-TABLE), showing that we need support for `=`, `<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=` for `raster`. Do we have those?

```
regress=# select oprname from pg_operator where oprname IN ('=', '<=', '<', '>', '>=') and oprleft = 'raster'::regtype and oprright = 'raster'::regtype;
 oprname 
---------
 =
(1 row)
```

Nope. So we can't create a b-tree operator class for `raster` without first implementing ordering operators for it and making sure that those operators follow the required rules about transitivity, commutivity, etc.

That's not overly surprisingly, since it's not clear what exactly `raster < raster` would actually mean. It does, however, mean you can't enable unique index support easily for `raster`.

---

Another possibility would be to hash the input with `md5` or similar, then create a unique index on the hash. This solves the index operator type issues and the problems with maximum b-tree entry sizes.

Creating indexes on hashed values is well documented elsewhere.

Comment: hmm.. I have partially understood.
Unfortunately, the same error exists even in PostgreSQL-9.3.4(PostGIS-2.1.2) version also. I have just checked.
I really appreciate your elaborate explanation.

Zia

Comment: @Zia If the underlying operators for the `raster` type exist, you might just be able to `CREATE OPERATOR CLASS` for it yourself.

Comment: How to check if the desired operator exists? I was trying to `Create Operator Class` but not sure how exactly I should proceed. Any sample example?

By the way, when I imported my raster ASCII file through Terminal, I do put the `Add Constraints` flag ("-C" in the following code) and that worked fine before me dropping those constraints. 

`raster2pgsql -d -I -C -M -F -t 100x100 -s 4326 us_tmin.asc chp05.us_tmin | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres1 -d database1`

Now when I am again adding those dropped constraints, there is this issue.

Comment: @Zia See edit. In short - the required operators don't exist, so you can't just create an opclass. As for what you're saying with `-C` and "add constraints" ... show me the SQL or the output of `\d+ thetablename` in psql, I can't really say anything useful w/o that.

Comment: Coz you coined-up so many new terminologies, it took me a while to go through some online-tutorials to get myself comfortable :) 

`See edit` section makes proper sense why unique indexing is not feasible for `raster`.

What is `regtype`?

Comment: Coz of characters limit I am pasting the main PSQL output
`Indexes:
    "us_tmin_with_const_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (rid)
    "us_tmin_with_const_rast_gist" gist (st_convexhull(rast))
Check constraints:
    "enforce_height_rast" CHECK (st_height(rast) = ANY (ARRAY[100, 21]))
    "enforce_max_extent_rast" CHECK (st_coveredby(st_convexhull(rast), '0103000020E6100000010000002D0000008AAAAAAAAA9E50C0B6AAAAAAAA1A3D408AAAAAAAAA9E50C00200000000F038408AAAAAAAAA9E50C555***:
``

Comment: @Zia Edit the question, add the new info there, then comment here when done. That way it's readable. Or use a pastebin site.

Answer (score 4):

As [Craig explained very well](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/74307/3684), you cannot create a unique index on the type `raster` without all the necessary operators.

Your second best bet to enforce uniqueness is to create a [functional index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-expressional.html) on the `text` representation:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX us_tmin_enforce_scalex_rast
ON chp05.us_tmin (cast(rast as text))
```

Note that this *cannot* be implemented as `CONSTRAINT`, as my code example suggested in my first draft. [Unique constraints only work on *columns*, not *expressions*.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) Needs to be a `UNIQUE INDEX`.

Details about `cast()` in a functional index:

- [How to create an index on an integer json property in postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54539/how-to-create-an-index-on-an-integer-json-property-in-postgres/54549#54549)

However, there may be multiple possible `text` representations for the same `raster` value (as identified by the `=` operator). It is your responsibility to rule out side effects from that.

Since we cast the *value*, we get the canonical `text` representation and additional variants due to noise characters in allowed input literals are folded already. But there may be more.

If one or more columns are to big to be indexed, the only remaining option is to create the index on a hash value:

- [Index max row size error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25138/index-max-row-size-error/25140#25140)

Comment: Thx a lot Erwin.
So mainly what you are suggesting is to change the `raster` datatype to the `text`. But can't we change it to something like `int` in order to apply mathematical operators (>, <, = ...) also?

Plus I am getting this error:
`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "cast"
LINE 1: ...s_tmin ADD CONSTRAINT enforce_scalex_rast unique (cast(rast ...`. Any idea?

Comment: Good idea. It didn't occur to me. There is a possible issue with that though (one that would also affect a native raster btree index) - the limit on varlena index entries of PAGESIZE/2,  i.e. 4k or so. I'd look at hashing it and using a unique index on the hash; there is a tiny risk of collisions, but really really tiny.

Comment: Actually by using `-C` flag in the Terminal to import my raster file into the Db, my primary aim is not to bring uniqueness but the following rules in one go:

`enforce_scalex_rast` & `enforce_scaley_rast`: This rule states that all the rasters must have the same scale X and Y. `enforce_max_extent_rast`, `enforce_srid_rast`, `enforce_out_db_rast`, `enforce_width_rast`, `enforce_height_rast`, `enforce_same_alignment_rast`, `enforce_num_band_rast`, `enforce_pixel_types_rast`, `enforce_nodata_values_rast` and `enforce_max_extent_rast`.

Comment: @Zia Argh, why didn't you say so? You should post a new, corrected question with that information and the other details you've since supplied, and link back to this one for context.

Comment: @Zia: I can't make sense of the error message. The fragment you posted looks unsuspicious. You would have to post the complete statement. Also, what Craig said: post a new question for your actual requirements.

Comment: @Craig Oh! I am sorry. Just to keep the post short and concise, I missed some useful prior-info. My bad.
Here is the new post [link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/74469/45802). Hope its fine.

@Erwin My Statement: `alter table chp05.us_tmin
add constraint enforce_scalex_rast unique (cast(rast as text))` and Error Message: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "cast"
LINE 2: add constraint enforce_scalex_rast unique (cast(rast as text...
                                                   ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "cast"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 70`

Thx a lot

Comment: @Zia: Oh, my bad. My code example suggested a constraint, but it must be just an index. Consider the updated answer. This works, I tested.

Comment: @Erwin: `Program Limit Exceeded` error

`ERROR:  index row requires 77384 bytes, maximum size is 8191
********** Error **********

ERROR: index row requires 77384 bytes, maximum size is 8191
SQL state: 54000`

I think changing the `raster` datatype to the `text` is not a good idea, especially for the big `raster` images.

Comment: @Zia: We are not "changing" the data type, just creating a functional index on the unchanged column. Obviously, one or more `raster` columns are too big. The remaining option would be a unique index on a hash value, like Craig already mentioned. [More in this related answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25138/index-max-row-size-error/25140#25140). It's not clear, whether that would solve your actual problem. [You seem to have more constraints.](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74469/adding-standard-set-of-constraints-rules-to-postgis-raster-type-column)